# Difference between dvipdf executables

Tags: pdf, dvi

What is the difference between the different dvipdf executables in \MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin

```
dvipdfm.exe
dvipdfmx.exe
dvipdft.exe
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dvipdft is a thumpnailer for `dvipdfm`, `dvipdfmx` is an extended `dvipdfm`, in new TeX distributions `dvipdfm` is actually `dvipdfmx` running in compatibility mode.

See also [The DVIPDFMx Project](http://project.ktug.or.kr/dvipdfmx/)

Comment: from the man page it looks like a wrapper around dvips that asks ghostscript for pdf output instead.

Answer (score 9):

And, just before you ask, `xdvipdfmx` is an extension of `dvipdfmx` used by XeTeX.